# Sticky nav issue

Tags: jquery, nav, sticky

first to mention I am learning jquery at the moment and I have almost no undesrtanding of it. I want to use in my site for my sticky navigation. This is my markup:

```
<div class="navbar">
<nav>
    <p id="navLogo">Forza</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#services" class="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#testemonials" class="nav-link">Testemonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team" class="nav-link">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#features" class="nav-link">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news" class="nav-link">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

When the page loads the background is transperant, the logo and the links are white. When I scroll down I want the background to become white and the links and logo to change their color so I use the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#services');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
    if (startchange.length){
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $(".navbar").css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95)')
          $("nav").css('margin-top', '10px');
          $("#navLogo").css('color', '#4d4141');
          $(".nav-link").css('color', '#4d4141');
       } else {
          $('.navbar').css('background-color', 'transparent');
          $("nav").css('margin-top', '35px');
          $("#navLogo").css('color', '#fff');
          $(".nav-link").css('color', '#fff');
       }
   });
    }
});
```

And it works just fine. But I also want the Services link in the nav to receive class active when i scroll to the services section, same with all other links, class active is set to different color. For this i use the following code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {

        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});
```

Now when I scroll down the link receives class active but the first jquery overrides its color property and it stays the same color.
How can I combine these two so they both work together. Please note that I am complete novice to jquery so only very specific advice would help me.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: CSS uses [specificity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to determine which rules win. The local style, set by the scroll handler, is winning over the class rule. In your style you can try adding [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) after the color in the class or change the class assignment to set a local style through `.css` but then order will matter (the order which the action happens.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! ! important solved the problem. Cheers! :)